# opening UITabController with Segue from UIViewController - how can I show the 3rd tab as the default one?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, uitabcontroller

I have a swift app and on my UIViewController I have a button. In my `StoryBoard` I attached the button to the `UITabController` and now when user clicks it - he gets redirected to it. But, by default, he is presented with the 1st tab. Is there a way of showing the 3rd tab instead?

This is the option of my segue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - but how complex it needs to be depends on what you're doing.

If you only ever go from the first `UIViewController` then you can simply add some code to the `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillLoad` function (remembering the index is zero-based)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

If you have more than one entry point, you can use the `prepareForSegue` to set a flag in the `tabBarController`.  In this example, I have two buttons on the `UIViewController` with `tag` values set as 100, and 200

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TabBarSegue"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? myTabBarViewController
        {
            if sender!.tag == 100
            {
                destinationVC.jumpToTab2 = true
            }
            if sender!.tag == 200
            {
                destinationVC.jumpToTab2 = false
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and then in the `TabBarController`, I have defined a flag `jumpToTab2`

```
class myTabBarViewController: UITabBarController
{
    var jumpToTab2 : Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        if jumpToTab2
        {
            self.selectedIndex = 2
        }
        jumpToTab2 = false // reset the flag before next time
    }
}
```